# I changed my thermostat, not my heat does not work... help!

Tags: electrical, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I know I made a mistake, but here's the storey.

When I was hooking up the new thermostat I did it with live wires, and I used metal pliers (metal touching metal).  The wires may have also touched each other during the process.  The thermostat didn't work (no power when connected to C), so I switched back to the old one and it still doesn't work.

Where do I start?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a voltmeter?  Assuming traditional wiring colors, is there voltage between the red wire and the blue C wire?

Comment: Check if there's a breaker or other reset in/on the furnace itself.

Comment: The 3 amp fuse needed to be replaced, but the real culprit was the disconnect box.  The box fried up and melted the connectors.

Answer (score -3):

Change 3amp fuse on control board in furnace

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A little more detail would be really helpful (e.g. how do you know it's a 3A fuse?). Thanks.